# While loop is broken, even though parameters are correct

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I am extremely confused about why my code is not running. I end up being in a loop that lasts forever that I assume is the while loop that happens after the print statement. The print statement that is listed prints true, so the while loop should go through at least one iteration... right?

This does not happen, my code ends up running forever, and does not end up printing anything else.

(Also just ignore the if statement with the `%`, I am testing on a small scale before going big.)

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(modifiedCSV);
int counter = 0;

System.out.println(scan.hasNextLine() && counter < 10);
while(scan.hasNextLine() && counter < 10);
{
    System.out.println("test");
    if(counter%1000000==0)
    {
        System.out.println("Normalizing Line: " + counter);
    }
    String line = scan.nextLine();
    String[] lineData = line.split(",");
    System.out.println("!!!!!!");
    double normalizedDistance = (Double.parseDouble(lineData[3])-minDistance)/(maxDistance-minDistance);
    double normalizedAngle = (Double.parseDouble(lineData[7])-minAngle)/(maxAngle-minAngle);
    double normalizedFlux = (Double.parseDouble(lineData[8])-minFlux)/(maxFlux-minFlux);
    
    fw.write(line + "," + normalizedDistance + "," + normalizedAngle + "," + normalizedFlux + "\n");
    counter++;
}
```

Comment: You have a semicolon after your loop declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your while loop is empty since there is a semicolon at the end of the line with the while statement.

```
while(scan.hasNextLine() && counter < 10);
```

Comment: I hate myself... I've been staring at this for hours now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Lol know that feeling :) no problem and good luck!